# How to run a jar together with faketime

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, time

I need run a certain `jar` file with a mock time for testing purposes. When I execute the jar in the usual way

```
$ java -jar myjar.jar
```

it runs perfectly. But when I try to run it together with `faketime` it either stops without executing the jar or kept hanging with cursor blinking and I am not getting the appropriate logs or terminal output for the executed jar. I have tried following commands with `faketime`

```
$ faketime '2015-10-10 17:28:00' /bin/java 'java -jar myjar.jar'
$ faketime '2015-10-10 17:28:00' /bin/java 'java -jar /full/path/to/myjar.jar'
$ faketime '2015-10-10 17:28:00' /bin/bash start.sh
```

For the last command I used the following simple shell script.

```
#!bin/bash
java -jar myjar.jar
```

Neither of the above methods executed the jar. Can you point out what is wrong here and how can I get this running.

- Both jar and shell script are executable and I have the proper privileges.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by "it fails"? What behaviour are you seeing? Is the fake date/time not taken into account?

Comment: @StephenKitt Edited question. To put it simply I'm not seeing the jar getting executed.

Comment: Doesn't `faketime '2015-10-10 17:28:00' java -jar myjar.jar` work?

Comment: No. It just hangs with a blinking cursor.

Comment: Also with the `-m` option?

Comment: Works for me. Which JVM are you using? Please post a sample program that causes a problem.

Answer (score 2):

this issue is fixed now
by setting the environment variable **DONT_FAKE_MONOTONIC=1**
you can go through this link  https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime/issues/109

Answer (score 1):

suppose you try [libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime)...
so this is from README:

> 2. Compatibility issues
>      ...
>
>    - Java-/JVM-based applications and others with a complex run-time environment
>        are known to not, or not reliably, work with libfaketime.

instead for java you could use something like https://github.com/arvindsv/faketime